# Open Skype or Gtalk in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, xcode4

I want to open Skype or Gtalk in iPhone's webview by just using a URL.
Similar to something like the URL Scheme's provided by Apple for opening Apple Mail mailTo:// , messaging API sms://, telephone tel:// and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to create a link using a predefined URL scheme for the app in question.

A reasonably comprehensive database of URL schemes can be found on the [Akosma wiki page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes).

The page above assumes linking from Cocoa-Touch controls. To link from within a UIWebView (i.e. from an html link) simply use the scheme they define in the `stringWithURL:` line.

EDIT: Just checked the above linked page and sadly they don't list schemes for Skype of Gtalk. Hopefully the link should give you some idea of what you're looking for though, and then you may be able to find the specific schemes you require after a bit of searching.

Answer (score 1):

For the Skype use an official links [generator](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-us/tell-a-friend/get-a-skype-button/) (the url itself might be found in the `Copy & paste this code` below)

Unoficial Skype and Gtalk url schemes might be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

Answer (score 1):

Skyle URLs are relatively easy, in the format:

> skype:username?call

For google talk, according to [this link](http://juberti.blogspot.com/2006/11/gtalk-uri.html), it should be something like:

> gtalk:call?jid=username@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

There is lists of openURL:

http://applookup.com/2010/09/iphone-apps-with-special-url-shortcuts/
http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"skype:%@?call",userSkype];
NSURL *URL          = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
```

URL will be `nil` if your `userSkype` is not valid -
extra spaces, etc.